# Rename by list() variable name rather than index in R

Tags: r, list, variables

I am running regressions over a list() of items using a for loop and I would like to replace the reference to the given list input with the name of that variable rather than its index. For example:

```
frame <- data.frame(y = rnorm(10), x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10) ) 
x.list <- list(frame$x1,frame$x2,frame$x3)  
fit <- list()

for(i in 1:length(x.list)){ fit[[i]] <- summary(lm(frame$y ~ x.list[[i]]))}         
fit
```

I would like each item in fit to refer to "x1", "x2", "x3" instead of "x.list[[i]]". Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Comment: `frame` is a function; maybe you could call it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't define `x.list`, just iterate over the names:

```
fit <- vector("list",3)
for ( i in c("x1","x2","x3") ) fit[[i]] <- summary(lm(frame$y ~ frame[[i]]))
```

---

**Save `lm`s instead.** It's likely that you'll want more than the summary, so just save the `lm`s:

```
xs     <- c("x1","x2","x3")
xs     <- setNames(xs,xs)
fit_lm <- lapply(xs,function(i)lm(frame$y ~ frame[[i]]))
```

You can look at `summary` with `lapply(fit_lm,summary)`, but also look at coefficients, with

```
sapply(fit_lm,`[[`,"coefficients")
#                    x1         x2          x3
# (Intercept) 0.1417501  0.2974165  0.25085281
# frame[[i]]  0.2318912 -0.1468433 -0.08783857
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a return value, `lapply` is preferable:

```
xs <- names(frame)[-1]

setNames(
  lapply(xs, function(x, dat) {
    f <- as.formula(paste("y", x, sep = "~"))
    summary(lm(f, data = dat))
  }, dat = frame), 
  xs)
```

However, the same strategy would work with a `for` loop.